# What suit of components do I need to get installed to start with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a requirement for a GIS product and following advice from firends and colleagues have decided that Quantum GIS seems suitable for what I need. I have input a request to our IT section to install it on our network laptop but this needs to be done by an engineer because of prohibited install functions as is normal on corp networks.

Anyway - my question is, i will be using QGIS to interpret things like Ordnance Survey Codepoint with polygone and Boundary data to make bespoke geography shapefiles of our organisational areas  (made up from clusters of postcode districts).

Could you advise what suit of components i would need to request to be installed to start with (so that i can get up and running without having to raise seperate requests to bolt on plugins at a later date).

Any help appreciated - can't wait to get started on it!

Comment: FYI, once QGIS is installed, you won't need admin rights to install plugins. I'd suggest that you have your IT person install it using the OSGEO4W setup utility (http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/), that will install QGIS as well as several other commonly used open source GIS programs. Use the "Desktop" installation.

Comment: Brilliant Dan. Thanks. I will point them in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend the Sextante Toolbox.  It is part of the QGIS official repository and is available from the Python Plugin installer.  It's a nice suite of analysis and conversion tools that can be used in models and scripts.

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks for your help and hints on this.